# Replacing first and last characters in string (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I need to replace first and last character in random string. Why this code doesn't work?

```
function symbExchange(line) {  
    var tmp = line[0];  
    var str = line.replace(line[0], line[line.length-1]);  
    var str2 = str.replace(str[str.length-1], tmp);  
    return str2;
}
```

Comment: str.replace() will replace the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `replace` function returns a new string with some or all matches of a pattern replaced by a replacement.

If you need to swap characters, you can use a regex in your case (*but this is not the best implementation)*:

```
function symbExchange(line) {  
    var tmp = line[0];  
    var str = line.replace(new RegExp('^' + line[0]), line[line.length-1]);  
    var str2 = str.replace(new RegExp(str[str.length-1] + '$'), tmp);  
    return str2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work because replace function will replace the first occurrence

try this :

```
function symbExchange(line) {  
    var first = line[0];  
    var last = line[line.length-1];  
    line[0] = last;
    line[line.length-1] = first
    return str2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line replaces first occurence of character that is same as last character. Not the last character itself.

```
var str2 = str.replace(str[str.length-1], tmp);
```

possible solution is not to use replace function:

```
function symbExchange(line) {  
    var startCh = line[0];  
    var endCh = line[line.length-1];
    var str = line;
    str[0] = endCh;
    str[str.length-1] = startCh;
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

String.Replace when used with a string argument will only replace the first occurrence of that string. You either need to use regex as an argument, or do a split 'n' join. Which one is better /faster will depend on the length of your string and number of occurrences to replace.

```
var src = "helloworldhello";
var dest = src.replace( /hello/g , "goodbye");
console.log(dest);
```

or

```
var src = "helloworldhello";
var dest = src.split("hello").join("goodbye");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use swapping characters after converting string to array and then to string

```
function symbExchange(line) {  

line = line.split("");
temp=line[0]
line[0]=line[line.length-1]
line[line.length-1]=temp
return line.join("")
}
```